# Python and Statsmodels: How to include the alternative test_t hypothesis?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Consider the following example:

> ```
> df = pd.read_csv('myFile.txt',delim_whitespace=True,header=None)
> df.columns=['vary','vax1','varx2']
> y,X = ps.dmatrices('vary ~ varx1 + varx2',data=df, return_type='dataframe')
> model = sm.OLS(y,X) # Describe Model
> results = model.fit() # Fit model
> print results.summary()
>
> hypotheses = 'varx1 = 0.0'
> t_test = results.t_test(hypotheses)
> print(t_test)
> ```

This is testing "H0: The coefficient of varX1 is zero" against the alternative hypothesis "H1: The coefficient of varX1 is different from zero"

I would like to make "H1: The coefficient of VarX1 is less than -c, c>0" (the one-sided alternative).

Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not supported yet. For a single t_test you can just divide the p-value by 2, if you are in the correct tail, i.e. the observed effect is in the direction of the alternative. The `c` value can be specified in the `hypotheses`.

Answer (score 1):

Statsmodels doesn't seem to allow one-tailed tests. You can instead invoke [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html#scipy.stats.t) after fitting your model:

```
from scipy import stats
c = 0.5 #lower bound
print(stats.t.cdf(var_x1, df, loc=c, scale=1))
```

which will give you the area under the t-dist to the right of c.